# Find files containing string and move this an corresponding file to other directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu

I have some files like that in one directory

```
00.01.02 0000 some filename 1.pdf
00.01.02 0000 some filename 1.txt
02.03.07 0163 another filename 2.pdf
02.03.07 0163 another filename 2.txt
```

and I have to find all txt file containing a specific string and then move this txt file and its corresponding pdf file to another directory.

What is the best way to get this done?

Comment: The tool you want is `find`. I think this question might be closed if you don't make it more focused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got 3 options for you, the Basic ideas are:

1. `grep | xargs mv`
2. `grep | parallel mv`
3. `find -exec grep -q -exec mv`

---

## 1. `grep | xargs mv`

Use `grep` and `xargs`:

```
grep -FlZ "some string" *.txt \
| xargs -0 -I{} sh -c 'echo mv "$1" "${1%.*}.pdf" some/other/directory' xargs-sh {}
```

`grep`:

- `-F` match a full string, not a pattern
- `-l` output matching filenames only
- `-Z` output zero-delimiter between filenames (This is important, because filenames are allowed to have newlines, so you cannot rely on a newline as the delimiter)

`xargs`:

- `-0` reads zero-delimited data

---

## 2. `grep | parallel mv`

With `xargs` you need to call a subshell using `sh -c` to  be able to get the corresponding pdf filename.

Instead of doing that, you can also make use of `GNU parallel` cool features !!

```
grep -FlZ "some string" *.txt \
| parallel -0 -j1 echo mv {} {.}.pdf some/other/directory
```

- `-j1` only one job at a time
- `{}` the filename
- `{.}` filename without extension

---

## 3. `find -exec grep -q -exec mv`

And another alternative, using `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.txt" \
-exec grep -Fq "some string" {} \; \
-exec sh -c 'echo mv "$1" "${1%.*}.pdf" some/other/location' find-sh {} \;
```

- `-maxdepth 1` to not recurse
- `grep -q` to just get the error code instead of file names, the second `-exec` will only run when the first one was successful.
- Second `-exec` is basically the same as in `xargs` in the first option.
- we don't need to do any zero-delimited output thing, because we don't pass any file names, `find` takes care of it.

---

For each option, remove the `echo` if you're happy with the output.

Answer (score 1):

Break down the problem into pieces.

"I need to find all text files containing a given string in the current directory".

```
grep -F "text string just as written (no regex)" *.txt
```

"I want the *file names* of those files"

```
grep -l -F "text string" *.txt
```

"For each of those files, move..."

```
grep -l -F "text string" *.txt \
| while IFS= read -r file ; do \
    BASE=$( basename ${file} .txt )
    mv ${BASE}.txt /some/other/dir
    mv ${BASE}.pdf /some/other/dir
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have `parallel` command , do with two `xargs` as below

```
grep -l 'search string' *.txt | xargs -I {} basename {} .txt | xargs -I {} cp {}.pdf /destination-directory
```